# Create linux environment in C using execl and fork()

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, exec

I have created a program that acts like a Linux environment. You put in a command and it does it for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

int pid;
int status;
printf("Enter command: ");
char s[256];
fgets(s,256,stdin);

const char *a[5];
int i = 0;
char* token = strtok(s, " ");
while(token)
{
    a[i] = strtok(s," ");   
    i++;
}

while (a[0] != "exit")
{
    if(a[0] = "cd")
    {
        chdir(a[1]);
    }

    else 
    {
      pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
        execvp(a[0],a);
        }
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            wait(&status);
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

It uses tokens to separate the parameters of the command. I tried running it and it compiles and runs but doesn't do the command I want. I think it might have something to do with the way it creates tokens. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger like `gdb`. Compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g`. And clear your `a[5]` array (which should be much bigger, or some heap allocated data). Look also into the source code of small free software shells (e.g. `sash`)

Comment: Also `a[0] != "exit"` is probably not what you want. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: You really need to take several hours to read a good C programming book. Then read a good Linux programming book like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/; spend a day or two for reading (perhaps in a library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
a[i] = strtok(s," ");
```

sets `a[i]` to a pointer within the string, which you're modifying and which may eventually have the temporary NUL characters (from `strtok`) removed.

You may want to try:

```
a[i] = strdup (strtok (s," "));
```

instead.

---

Let me explain further. Say we have the command (as it exists in memory):

```
ls -al xyzzy\0
```

When you `strtok` it, it almost certainly gets changed to:

```
ls\0-al xyzzy\0
^
```

and then it gives you `s` (indicated by `^`) returned from `strtok` and placed into `a[0]`. The next time through, it changes the string to:

```
ls -al\0xyzzy\0
   ^
```

and gives you the address indicated by `^` and places that into `a[1]`. Unfortunately, `a[0]` now points to the string `"ls -al"`

Eventually, the string will return to it's original state and your pointers, while pointing to the right *addresses,* won't have strings null-terminated as you expect (except for the last one).

So you'll end up with:

```
a[0] = "ls -al xyzzy"
a[1] = "-al xyzzy"
a[2] = "xyzzy"
```

By using `strdup`, you make a *copy* of each string (at the time when the string is as you expect, a single word), which isn't then modified by later operations in the string tokenising code.

Remember, however, to free all those strings you've allocated when you're done with them.

You can use this code as a baseline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[256], *word[20];
    int i, num, len;

    printf ("Enter command: ");
    fgets (str, sizeof (str), stdin);

    num = 0;
    word[num] = strtok (str, " ");
    while (word[num] != NULL) {
        word[num] = strdup (word[num]);
        len = strlen (word[num]);
        if (strlen (word[num]) > 0)
            if (word[num][len-1] == '\n')
                word[num][len-1] = '\0';
        word[++num] = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf ("%d: [%s]\n", i, (word[i] == NULL) ? "<<null>>" : word[i]);
        free (word[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the following transcript shows it in action:

```
Enter command: ls -al xyzzy | grep -v plugh
0: [ls]
1: [-al]
2: [xyzzy]
3: [|]
4: [grep]
5: [-v]
6: [plugh]
```

---

Additionally, the correct way to compare C strings is not:

```
if (a[0] = "cd")
```

since that compares *addresses,* which may be different even if the backing content is identical. You should instead use something like:

```
if (strcmp (a[0], "cd") == 0)
```

---

And one final thing, the `argv[]` array that you pass to `execvp` must have a final terminating NULL pointer. That's part of the contract, so you'll need to ensure that gets put in before calling `execvp`.

Comment: When I do `strdup (strtok(s," "));` anything I put in just gives me a blank line. I redid all my comparing statements to `strcmp`. I don't understand your last points about the execvp.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop `while (a[0] != "exit")` will never terminate. You are comparing pointers (memory addresses). You might want read about `strcmp()`.

The if statement `if(a[0] = "cd")` seems also not what I think you try to do. You are assigning the pointer to `"cd"` to `a[0]`. This common mistake would be catched if you used compiler diagnostics (probable intention was to use `==` instead which is also not going to work - again `strcmp()` is the thing to use for string comparison).

Comment: so `strcmp( a[0], char *string1)` in which string1 is set to exit? and one for the cd?

Comment: Even simpler `strcmp(a[0], "exit")` returns 0 if the two strings are equal (the char arrays contain exactly the same character until terminating `NUL`).

Comment: I did all the comparing with `strcmp` but I get segmentation fault when ever I put any command, including exit.

Comment: It is really time to learn how to use the debugger.